# Different answer SHA-256 code (online generator - Lua-script)

Tags: lua, sha256

What's the reason, that I get different results from an online SHA-256 calculator HASH-code and the code generated by the Lua script I've pasted?

Answer online: ba7816bf8f01cfea414140de5dae2223b00361a396177a9cb410ff61f20015ad

Answer script (with SciTE): a006267b0042805304ec162a0070030510452429204488c160351215ac00c19

```
--
--  Adaptation of the Secure Hashing Algorithm (SHA-244/256)
--  Found Here: http://lua-users.org/wiki/SecureHashAlgorithm
--
--  Using an adapted version of the bit library
--  Found Here: https://bitbucket.org/Boolsheet/bslf/src/1ee664885805/bit.lua
--
--  Adapted into a single function by GravityScore
--

local function sha256(msg)
        local function band(int1, int2, int3, ...)
                local ret =
                ((int1%0x00000002>=0x00000001 and int2%0x00000002>=0x00000001 and 0x00000001) or 0)+
                ((int1%0x00000004>=0x00000002 and int2%0x00000004>=0x00000002 and 0x00000002) or 0)+
                ((int1%0x00000008>=0x00000004 and int2%0x00000008>=0x00000004 and 0x00000004) or 0)+
                ((int1%0x00000010>=0x00000008 and int2%0x00000010>=0x00000008 and 0x00000008) or 0)+
                ((int1%0x00000020>=0x00000010 and int2%0x00000020>=0x00000010 and 0x00000010) or 0)+
                ((int1%0x00000040>=0x00000020 and int2%0x00000040>=0x00000020 and 0x00000020) or 0)+
                ((int1%0x00000080>=0x00000040 and int2%0x00000080>=0x00000040 and 0x00000040) or 0)+
                ((int1%0x00000100>=0x00000080 and int2%0x00000100>=0x00000080 and 0x00000080) or 0)+
                ((int1%0x00000200>=0x00000100 and int2%0x00000200>=0x00000100 and 0x00000100) or 0)+
                ((int1%0x00000400>=0x00000200 and int2%0x00000400>=0x00000200 and 0x00000200) or 0)+
                ((int1%0x00000800>=0x00000400 and int2%0x00000800>=0x00000400 and 0x00000400) or 0)+
                ((int1%0x00001000>=0x00000800 and int2%0x00001000>=0x00000800 and 0x00000800) or 0)+
                ((int1%0x00002000>=0x00001000 and int2%0x00002000>=0x00001000 and 0x00001000) or 0)+
                ((int1%0x00004000>=0x00002000 and int2%0x00004000>=0x00002000 and 0x00002000) or 0)+
                ((int1%0x00008000>=0x00004000 and int2%0x00008000>=0x00004000 and 0x00004000) or 0)+
                ((int1%0x00010000>=0x00008000 and int2%0x00010000>=0x00008000 and 0x00008000) or 0)+
                ((int1%0x00020000>=0x00010000 and int2%0x00020000>=0x00010000 and 0x00010000) or 0)+
                ((int1%0x00040000>=0x00020000 and int2%0x00040000>=0x00020000 and 0x00020000) or 0)+
                ((int1%0x00080000>=0x00040000 and int2%0x00080000>=0x00040000 and 0x00040000) or 0)+
                ((int1%0x00100000>=0x00080000 and int2%0x00100000>=0x00080000 and 0x00080000) or 0)+
                ((int1%0x00200000>=0x00100000 and int2%0x00200000>=0x00100000 and 0x00100000) or 0)+
                ((int1%0x00400000>=0x00200000 and int2%0x00400000>=0x00200000 and 0x00200000) or 0)+
                ((int1%0x00800000>=0x00400000 and int2%0x00800000>=0x00400000 and 0x00400000) or 0)+
                ((int1%0x01000000>=0x00800000 and int2%0x01000000>=0x00800000 and 0x00800000) or 0)+
                ((int1%0x02000000>=0x01000000 and int2%0x02000000>=0x01000000 and 0x01000000) or 0)+
                ((int1%0x04000000>=0x02000000 and int2%0x04000000>=0x02000000 and 0x02000000) or 0)+
                ((int1%0x08000000>=0x04000000 and int2%0x08000000>=0x04000000 and 0x04000000) or 0)+
                ((int1%0x10000000>=0x08000000 and int2%0x10000000>=0x08000000 and 0x08000000) or 0)+
                ((int1%0x20000000>=0x10000000 and int2%0x20000000>=0x10000000 and 0x10000000) or 0)+
                ((int1%0x40000000>=0x20000000 and int2%0x40000000>=0x20000000 and 0x20000000) or 0)+
                ((int1%0x80000000>=0x40000000 and int2%0x80000000>=0x40000000 and 0x40000000) or 0)+
                ((int1>=0x80000000 and int2>=0x80000000 and 0x80000000) or 0)

                return (int3 and band(ret, int3, ...)) or ret
        end

        local function bxor(int1, int2, int3, ...)
                local ret =
                ((int1%0x00000002>=0x00000001 ~= (int2%0x00000002>=0x00000001) and 0x00000001) or 0)+
                ((int1%0x00000004>=0x00000002 ~= (int2%0x00000004>=0x00000002) and 0x00000002) or 0)+
                ((int1%0x00000008>=0x00000004 ~= (int2%0x00000008>=0x00000004) and 0x00000004) or 0)+
                ((int1%0x00000010>=0x00000008 ~= (int2%0x00000010>=0x00000008) and 0x00000008) or 0)+
                ((int1%0x00000020>=0x00000010 ~= (int2%0x00000020>=0x00000010) and 0x00000010) or 0)+
                ((int1%0x00000040>=0x00000020 ~= (int2%0x00000040>=0x00000020) and 0x00000020) or 0)+
                ((int1%0x00000080>=0x00000040 ~= (int2%0x00000080>=0x00000040) and 0x00000040) or 0)+
                ((int1%0x00000100>=0x00000080 ~= (int2%0x00000100>=0x00000080) and 0x00000080) or 0)+
                ((int1%0x00000200>=0x00000100 ~= (int2%0x00000200>=0x00000100) and 0x00000100) or 0)+
                ((int1%0x00000400>=0x00000200 ~= (int2%0x00000400>=0x00000200) and 0x00000200) or 0)+
                ((int1%0x00000800>=0x00000400 ~= (int2%0x00000800>=0x00000400) and 0x00000400) or 0)+
                ((int1%0x00001000>=0x00000800 ~= (int2%0x00001000>=0x00000800) and 0x00000800) or 0)+
                ((int1%0x00002000>=0x00001000 ~= (int2%0x00002000>=0x00001000) and 0x00001000) or 0)+
                ((int1%0x00004000>=0x00002000 ~= (int2%0x00004000>=0x00002000) and 0x00002000) or 0)+
                ((int1%0x00008000>=0x00004000 ~= (int2%0x00008000>=0x00004000) and 0x00004000) or 0)+
                ((int1%0x00010000>=0x00008000 ~= (int2%0x00010000>=0x00008000) and 0x00008000) or 0)+
                ((int1%0x00020000>=0x00010000 ~= (int2%0x00020000>=0x00010000) and 0x00010000) or 0)+
                ((int1%0x00040000>=0x00020000 ~= (int2%0x00040000>=0x00020000) and 0x00020000) or 0)+
                ((int1%0x00080000>=0x00040000 ~= (int2%0x00080000>=0x00040000) and 0x00040000) or 0)+
                ((int1%0x00100000>=0x00080000 ~= (int2%0x00100000>=0x00080000) and 0x00080000) or 0)+
                ((int1%0x00200000>=0x00100000 ~= (int2%0x00200000>=0x00100000) and 0x00100000) or 0)+
                ((int1%0x00400000>=0x00200000 ~= (int2%0x00400000>=0x00200000) and 0x00200000) or 0)+
                ((int1%0x00800000>=0x00400000 ~= (int2%0x00800000>=0x00400000) and 0x00400000) or 0)+
                ((int1%0x01000000>=0x00800000 ~= (int2%0x01000000>=0x00800000) and 0x00800000) or 0)+
                ((int1%0x02000000>=0x01000000 ~= (int2%0x02000000>=0x01000000) and 0x01000000) or 0)+
                ((int1%0x04000000>=0x02000000 ~= (int2%0x04000000>=0x02000000) and 0x02000000) or 0)+
                ((int1%0x08000000>=0x04000000 ~= (int2%0x08000000>=0x04000000) and 0x04000000) or 0)+
                ((int1%0x10000000>=0x08000000 ~= (int2%0x10000000>=0x08000000) and 0x08000000) or 0)+
                ((int1%0x20000000>=0x10000000 ~= (int2%0x20000000>=0x10000000) and 0x10000000) or 0)+
                ((int1%0x40000000>=0x20000000 ~= (int2%0x40000000>=0x20000000) and 0x20000000) or 0)+
                ((int1%0x80000000>=0x40000000 ~= (int2%0x80000000>=0x40000000) and 0x40000000) or 0)+
                ((int1>=0x80000000 ~= (int2>=0x80000000) and 0x80000000) or 0)

                return (int3 and bxor(ret, int3, ...)) or ret
        end

        local function bnot(int)
                return 4294967295 - int
        end

        local function rshift(int, by)
                local shifted = int / (2 ^ by)
                return shifted - shifted % 1
        end

        local function rrotate(int, by)
                local shifted = int / (2 ^ by)
                local fraction = shifted % 1
                return (shifted - fraction) + fraction * (2 ^ 32)
        end

        local k = {
                0x428a2f98, 0x71374491, 0xb5c0fbcf, 0xe9b5dba5,
                0x3956c25b, 0x59f111f1, 0x923f82a4, 0xab1c5ed5,
                0xd807aa98, 0x12835b01, 0x243185be, 0x550c7dc3,
                0x72be5d74, 0x80deb1fe, 0x9bdc06a7, 0xc19bf174,
                0xe49b69c1, 0xefbe4786, 0x0fc19dc6, 0x240ca1cc,
                0x2de92c6f, 0x4a7484aa, 0x5cb0a9dc, 0x76f988da,
                0x983e5152, 0xa831c66d, 0xb00327c8, 0xbf597fc7,
                0xc6e00bf3, 0xd5a79147, 0x06ca6351, 0x14292967,
                0x27b70a85, 0x2e1b2138, 0x4d2c6dfc, 0x53380d13,
                0x650a7354, 0x766a0abb, 0x81c2c92e, 0x92722c85,
                0xa2bfe8a1, 0xa81a664b, 0xc24b8b70, 0xc76c51a3,
                0xd192e819, 0xd6990624, 0xf40e3585, 0x106aa070,
                0x19a4c116, 0x1e376c08, 0x2748774c, 0x34b0bcb5,
                0x391c0cb3, 0x4ed8aa4a, 0x5b9cca4f, 0x682e6ff3,
                0x748f82ee, 0x78a5636f, 0x84c87814, 0x8cc70208,
                0x90befffa, 0xa4506ceb, 0xbef9a3f7, 0xc67178f2,
        }


        local function str2hexa(s)
                local h = string.gsub(s, ".", function(c)
                        return string.format("%02x", string.byte(c))
                end)
                return h
        end

        local function num2s(l, n)
                local s = ""
                for i = 1, n do
                        local rem = l % 256
                        s = string.char(rem) .. s
                        l = (l - rem) / 256
                end
                return s
        end

        local function s232num(s, i)
                local n = 0
                for i = i, i + 3 do n = n*256 + string.byte(s, i) end
                return n
        end

        local function preproc(msg, len)
                local extra = 64 - ((len + 1 + 8) % 64)
                len = num2s(8 * len, 8)
                msg = msg .. "\128" .. string.rep("\0", extra) .. len
                return msg
        end

        local function initH256(H)
                H[1] = 0x6a09e667
                H[2] = 0xbb67ae85
                H[3] = 0x3c6ef372
                H[4] = 0xa54ff53a
                H[5] = 0x510e527f
                H[6] = 0x9b05688c
                H[7] = 0x1f83d9ab
                H[8] = 0x5be0cd19
                return H
        end

        local function digestblock(msg, i, H)
                local w = {}
                for j = 1, 16 do w[j] = s232num(msg, i + (j - 1) * 4) end
                for j = 17, 64 do
                        local v = w[j - 15]
                        local s0 = bxor(rrotate(v, 7), rrotate(v, 18), rshift(v, 3))
                        v = w[j - 2]
                        local s1 = bxor(rrotate(v, 17), rrotate(v, 19), rshift(v, 10))
                        w[j] = w[j - 16] + s0 + w[j - 7] + s1
                end

                local a, b, c, d, e, f, g, h = H[1], H[2], H[3], H[4], H[5], H[6], H[7], H[8]
                for i = 1, 64 do
                        local s0 = bxor(rrotate(a, 2), rrotate(a, 13), rrotate(a, 22))
                        local maj = bxor(band(a, b), band(a, c), band(b, c))
                        local t2 = s0 + maj
                        local s1 = bxor(rrotate(e, 6), rrotate(e, 11), rrotate(e, 25))
                        local ch = bxor (band(e, f), band(bnot(e), g))
                        local t1 = h + s1 + ch + k[i] + w[i]
                        h, g, f, e, d, c, b, a = g, f, e, d + t1, c, b, a, t1 + t2
                end

                H[1] = band(H[1], a)
                H[2] = band(H[2], b)
                H[3] = band(H[3], c)
                H[4] = band(H[4], d)
                H[5] = band(H[5], e)
                H[6] = band(H[6], f)
                H[7] = band(H[7], g)
                H[8] = band(H[8], h)
        end

        msg = preproc(msg, #msg)
        local H = initH256({})
        for i = 1, #msg, 64 do digestblock(msg, i, H) end
        return str2hexa(num2s(H[1], 4) .. num2s(H[2], 4) .. num2s(H[3], 4) .. num2s(H[4], 4) ..
                num2s(H[5], 4) .. num2s(H[6], 4) .. num2s(H[7], 4) .. num2s(H[8], 4))
end

test = sha256("abc");
print(test);
```

Comment: Are you running Lua 5.2? In this case, that horrible code can be a lot simplified, because there is the `bit32` module for bit manipulation. Notably, the functions `bit32.extract` and `bit32.replace` (added to Lua from my suggestion) can be quite handy.

Comment: It's a cashregister with is own lua-library. So, i use this sha-256 script without libraries, because the cashregister doesn't have. I 've just replace the str2hexa function with an other one, but no result.

Comment: This does not answer the question of which version you are using. And in the code there are `string.byte`, `string.rep`, `string.format`, ... functions which are from the standard library, so why not `bit32` (provided you are on Lua 5.2)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are two major bugs in your code.

The reference Lua 5.2 algorithm at http://lua-users.org/wiki/SecureHashAlgorithm, from which this code is adapted, gives correct answers.

First, the functions `band`, `rrotate` and `rshift` do not work properly because they expect **unsigned integers** and they sometimes receive negative values. To fix that, add a line telling something like `int = int % 2^32` at the start of all those functions to ensure the numbers are between **0** and **4294967295**.

There is a second problem. Compared to the reference implementation, the ending lines in the form of `H[1] = band(H[1] + a)` have been transformed into `H[1] = band(H[1], a)`. This is **not** the same thing! Replace them with something like `H[1] = (H[1] + a) % 2^32` and now the function gives correct answers.